# why spring data redis 2.x RedisCacheManager not have method "loadRemoteCacheKeys"

Tags: spring

In spring data redis 1.x, RedisCacheManager have method "loadRemoteCacheKeys" to get all cache keys from Redis when initializing;
but why in 2.x not have this method and not initialize any more?

Answer (score 0):

The `loadRemoteCacheKeys` [gets you the cache names](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/1.8.x/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/cache/RedisCacheManager.java#L277) in 1.8.x.

In 2.x, you can get the cache names with the [`RedisCacheManager#getCacheNames` method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.0.x/api/).